# How to connect two docker containers

Tags: spring, docker, containers, port, grpc

I have a Docker container running PostgreSQL, it runs fine since I can connect to it from IntelliJ. In another container I have a GRPC based app, which crashes immediately every time I try to run it because it needs to connect to the Postgres database running in the other container.

I've tried publishing the ports for both containers but nothings helps... I even got an error because I tried to map the two containers to the same ports, since the app connects to postgres on the port it runs on which is 5432 by default(I didn't change this).

I wonder how you go about connecting the two containers so that my app can access the database and I can test the GRPC requests.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Need more information. How are the containers started (what settings / options)? What is the relevant code connecting to PostgreSQL (what is the connection string)? What is the actual error (or if no output from container logs, what does "crashing" mean in this case)? Please also provide any relevant logs and container output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer:

You can't.

The best way is to have either both containers running on the host network(`--net host`) or one container running on another containers network(`--net container:<containerID>`).

Answer (score 1):

Make the app container run on port 5432 and expose it to any port and make the postgres container run on any port and exposes the port 5432

```
docker run -p xxx:5432 yourapp
docker run -p 5432:yyy postgres
```

need to insure that the postgres is running inside the container at port **yyy**

Comment: How would I go about making sure that postgres is listening on any port?